# Extract Colors and Sizes from string

Tags: c#

Given the following product names below. I have been tasked to extract all the colors and sizes.

Example: `Nike Relay Women's Running Capris - **Black**, **L/XS**`

```
Color = Black
Size = [XS,L]
```

What would be the best way to go about this? I was thinking of having a `dictionary` with all the colors and sizes and then just doing a match.

But there has to be a better way and more maintainable way.
The biggest problem that i see is that there are so many different combinations

1. Nautica S **Blue** Bone Woven Pajama Pants
2. Nike Relay Women's Running Capris - **Black**, **XS**
3. Nautica Mens J-Class Pajama Pants-**Small**, **NAVY**
4. Nautica J-Class Woven Pajama Pant **L**, **Maritime Navy**
5. Nike Legend Tank - Womens - **Black/Black**
6. Nike 3PK DF Cushion No Show Tab Socks - Womens - **Black/White/Black**
7. Stance Casual Socks - Men's Mahalo, **L/XL**
8. Nautica Wrinkle Resistant Dress Pant **30x30**, **Grey**
9. Nautica Wrinkle Resistant Dress Pant **36x30**, **Black**
10. Nautica Wrinkle Resistant Dress Pant **33x32**, **Black**
11. RVCA VA Flipped Box Slim T-Shirt - Short-Sleeve - Men's **Bluestone**,
     **L**
12. RVCA VA Flipped Box Slim T-Shirt - Short-Sleeve - Men's **Bluestone**,
     **M**
13. RVCA VA Flipped Box Slim T-Shirt - Short-Sleeve - Men's **Bluestone**,
     **S**

Comment: The better and more maintainable way is to put the size and color in the product name in a pre-defined format.

Comment: Yea, the problem is the data that you are seeing now comes from an API, that we don't have control over.

Comment: It looks like you won't be able to write a parser (or it will be really difficult and you will update it every time you get a new size \ color declaration). As for me, it is better to implement a self-learning recognizing algorithm. If it meets the unknown declaration of size \ color, it should inform you so that you can teach it. Bu that's another story - a long, difficult and full of complex models and algorithms.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, lol i was hoping for something simpler

Comment: @manish, nope. its from https://www.popshops.com/

Answer (score 3):

this's is time taking but serves the purpose, the whole idea is you have to have a `List`/`Collection` of available `colors` and `sizes` and then iterate over them one by one an check

```
enum ColorBase {
    [Description("Blue")] //by using System.ComponentModel;  
    Blue,
    [Description("White")]
    White,
    [Description("Grey")]
    Grey,
    [Description("Magenta")]
    Magenta,
    [Description("Pale")]
    Pale,
    [Description("MaryTime Navy")]
    MaryTimeNavy,
    [Description("Navy")]
    Navy,
    [Description("Bluestone")]
    Bluestone,
}

enum SizeBase
{
    [Description("XL")]
    XL,
    [Description("XXL")]
    XXL,
    [Description("L")]
    L,
    [Description("M")]
    M,
    [Description("S")]
    S,
    [Description("XS")]
    XS,
    [Description("3X30")]
    S30X30,
    [Description("36X30")]
    S36X30,
    [Description("33X32")]
    S33X32
}
```

A helper method by using `System.Reflection`which will return the `Description` of `enum` declared above

```
 public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```

and here's the accessing of them all :-

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      List<string> availableColorsAndSizes = new List<string>();

        string item = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder mediator = new StringBuilder();

        List<string> capries = new List<string>{"Nautica S Blue Bone Woven Pajama Pants",
                                                "Nike Relay Women's Running Capris - Black, XS",
                                                "Nautica Mens J-Class Pajama Pants-Small, NAVY",
                                                "Nautica J-Class Woven Pajama Pant L, Maritime Navy",
                                                "Nike Legend Tank - Womens - Black/Black",
                                                "Nike 3PK DF Cushion No Show Tab Socks - Womens - Black/White/Black",
                                                "Stance Casual Socks - Men's Mahalo, L/XL",
                                                "Nautica Wrinkle Resistant Dress Pant 30x30, Grey",
                                                "Nautica Wrinkle Resistant Dress Pant 36x30, Black",
                                                "Nautica Wrinkle Resistant Dress Pant 33x32, Black",
                                                "RVCA VA Flipped Box Slim T-Shirt - Short-Sleeve - Men's Bluestone, L",
                                                "RVCA VA Flipped Box Slim T-Shirt - Short-Sleeve - Men's Bluestone, M",
                                                "RVCA VA Flipped Box Slim T-Shirt - Short-Sleeve - Men's Bluestone, S",
                                                };

        foreach (var caprie in capries)
        {
            string[] words = caprie.Split(); //added this for WORD level precison
            foreach (ColorBase colorBase in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ColorBase)))
            {
                item = Program.GetEnumDescription(colorBase);
                if (caprie.Contains(item))
                    if (!mediator.ToString().Contains(item + ":"))//just to confirm that it's not being added to the same twice
                        mediator.Append(item + ":");
            }
            foreach (SizeBase sizeBase in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SizeBase)))
            {
                item = Program.GetEnumDescription(sizeBase);
                if (caprie.Contains(item))
                    if (!mediator.ToString().Contains(item + ":"))
                        mediator.Append(item);
            }
            mediator.Append("|"); //identifies a pair of 'Color' and 'Size'
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Availabe Parameters");

        string[] colorsAndSizes = mediator.ToString().Split('|');

        foreach (var clrSiz in colorsAndSizes)
        {
            Console.Write("Color : {0}", clrSiz.Split(':')[0]);
            if(clrSiz.Split(':').Length > 1)
                Console.Write(" ,Size : {0}", clrSiz.Split(':')[1]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
 }
```

Comment: At first glance i think something like this might work, i do think however the sizes might might not work 100% because if you use the work Slim T-Shirt, will that not return SS? Because of the [Description("S")]

Comment: i agree that needed a word level of precision, `edited` it with
`string[] words = caprie.Split();` it might need some other tweak as i don't have your all data and scenario :)

Comment: upvote, still looking around a bit. But so far this will prob work the best.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do a hierarchical regex building. I've created such a system with good effects, though it was for log parsing.

```
//basic definitions:
String colorsRegex = "(?black|red|blue|orange|navy|cyan|white)";
String sizesRegex = "(?small|large|medium)";
String sizesShortRegex = "(?s|m|l|xl|xxl|xxxl)";

// some more complex definitions
// always start the array with the most complex regex, so that as much is captured as possible ("blue-green" instead of just "blue")
String[] colorFinders = {"("+colorsRegex+"[/- ]+)+", colorsRegex};
String[] sizesFinders = {"("+sizesRegex+"[/- ]+)+", "("+sizesShortRegex+"[/- ]+){2,}", sizesRegex};

// match the string for each complex definition
```

For each line that doesn't get matched (or properly matched) by this system build a dedicated "finder". Repeat until all data is matched.

Watch out for invalid cross-matches. Log unmatched lines in test and production environment. Remember to watch for partial matches and exclude any parts of string which could confuse your algorithm (imagine a company named "blue moon", it would always get matched).